# What Massachusetts licence(s) are required for multisplit installation by the homeowner?

Tags: electrical, hvac, air-conditioning

I'm looking at a 3-circuit 2.5 ton MrCool DIY multi-split.  The utility wants it installed by a licensed contractor as condition for rebate, but other than the electrical hookup, it is not clear what contractor license is needed for this work.

Background: I did gut renovation of my 1920 1.5-storey home in Ft Collins, CO 1984 when/where homeowner could do wiring and plumbing without any licenses; the work was permitted and passed all inspections.  I got the EPA certificate for handling refrigerants 25 years ago.  I have vac pump and digital gauges and plenty of refrig. experience in academic research settings.  My motivation is to learn what other DIY homeowners have encountered and any authoritative references that exist before approaching MA building officials on the matter.

Comment: If your criteria is to receive a rebate, you really need to ask the person offering the rebate what they mean by "licensed".   Very often, "licensed" only means having a business license and business insurance.

Answer (score 3):

You can install a MrCool DIY model without a refrigeration license.  That's the whole point of the product, they do very clever things with the line-set terminations so you never get anywhere near the Freon (you need a special EPA license to mess with freon). And this whole deal is UL Listed that way: UL *approved it* for DIY installation.

So the answer to the licensure question is "none required".

You probably still need to pull a permit and have inspections.

---

What your *rebate* requires is another matter altogether.  And that is subject to the whimsy of the rebate issuer.

If I'm paying you $100 to install a heat pump, I might require that the contractor have the letter "J" in their business name somewhere.

However more realistically I would set terms & conditions to assure you use the thing for many years (otherwise what's the point). Thus, I would insist that the contractor who installs it offer a long warranty. I would look for that from the contractor, not the manufacturer, because there are lots of ways an installer can void a warranty by being inept.

Comment: If OP obtained EPA certification for refrigerants in 1984, that likely covers R22 "Freon". Unless, of course, all the rules about certifications have changed since then (highly likely) and/or the license has expired (entirely possible).

Comment: @FreeMan the problem is, the requirement isn't about the medallion. 1984 requirements were about not wasting freon, i.e. don't go "pssssssst" casually.  Today's requirements are about total life-cycle control of freon so that "psssst" never happens.  You need different equipment, storage tanks and supply-chain connections to end-life all old freon. Your supplier either chemically destroys it, or purifies it for re-use (this being the ONLY source for R12 and R22 since no one makes it anymore, even China signed onto that agreement).

Comment: Mass save rebate eligibility is clear: “equipment must be installed by a licensed contractor.” You can only guess the rationale, but since it’s a subsidized program, perhaps they think that makes it more likely to meet the energy saving benefit objective.

Comment: Does anyone know (based on rebates actually granted) what kind of license is acceptable?  MA has the following license types: construction supervisor; plumbing*; electrician*; and home-improvement (HIC)...but not refrigeration. (*multiple levels).

Comment: @parmstr because it's Federal. https://www.acca.org/certification/epa

Comment: @Harper, do you know for sure that MassSave accepts EPA 608 without any other type of Mass.gov contractors license?  I have an EPA 608 certificate (since 1995).  Thanks!

Comment: @Harper: ...but I only used the EPA 608 to purchase and recycle refrigerants for research projects.  I never did refrigeration contract work.  Hence the feeling that my question is valid/non-trivial.

Comment: @Tim B: can you answer this question?  i.e. is the Home Improvement Contractor license, together with the EPA 608 certificate, sufficient so long as I get a licensed electrician to run the wires?

Comment: @parmstr don't know, that's a question for the state regulator.  Note that certification is a hell of a lot more than a card in your wallet. You also need the equipment to successfully vampire refrigerants, and the supply chain relationships to pass back the collected refrigerant for polishing/reuse or destruction.  If yours is 1995 it's probably obsolete. Much has changed.

Comment: @harper I do have the equipment: vac pump, recovery machine & tanks, gage set, surface temperature probes, Pirani gage, flaring/bending/swaging tools, oxy-acetylene set, etc.  The national supply houses (ABCO, URI, Johnstone Supply...) are, in my experience, happy to see knowledgeable reefer people drop in, no matter how old the card or cardholder.  Getting back to my question...do you (or anyone out there) happen to have an email address and ph# of the appropriate state regulator or Eversource/MassSave rebate manager?